# Orphaned java process IBM Websphere 5.1

Tags: java, websphere, httpserver, documentum

I have an application developed using Documentum and deployed in Websphere server 5.1 and http server 2.0.47. On every start and stop of the process we are using the windows script. We are stopping the server to backup the data. On every time we are stopping app server. we scheduled the back up process to run on daily basis and automated the statup process. Most cases it is failed due to idle process creation. Any idea on how does this idle process are created. we have pid mapped to each process thats running in the server.

Comment: WAS 5.1 is out of support for many years now, almost nobody is using it any more. I suggest to update to the newer version. Also your problem description is very vague. how it is failing (any stacktraces)? What idle process?

Comment: we have scheduled the backup process of the content server. at that time to avoid the content access we are stopping the server using service. after back up we are restarting the server.some times it is getting started successfully without any issues. but some time, the pid mentioned in the server log file is different than the process id tagged to its server when we check in task manager. Is there way to identify what is that process?

Answer (score 0):

the application is hosted on a WebSphere 5.1 server. There are 5 java processes (one for each service related to the application) running on the server. At times, there is an additional java process which is created. This will stop the application from functioning. Once we kill the extra process and restart the services, the application works as expected. We are unable to identify how this extra process is being triggered. We would like to know if there is any specific logs where we can check for this or any if we can collect any specific traces which will point out the reason for this additional java process.